# Return value of a intermediate step of a recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, immutability

Got a simple script aims to determine path existence between `x` and `y`.

Through the implementation, I'd like to retrieve some intermediate values, but got myself lost in recursive calls. Basically, can someone help to distinguish the differences between these two implementations? Why they supplied distinct returns?

Quick note: the only difference is the flag part.

```
# i.e., adj: {1: {2}, 2: {1, 3}, 3: {2, 5}, 4: {5}, 5: {3, 4}, 11: {12}, 12: {11, 15}, 15: {12}}
```

#### Implementation 1

```
def dfs(adj, x, y, visited=None, flag=[]):
    if visited is None:
        visited = set()
    if x == y:
        flag.append(True)
    if x not in visited:
        visited.add(x)
    for neigh in adj[x]:
        if neigh not in visited:
            dfs(adj, neigh, y, visited, flag)

    return flag
```

Now:

```
dfs(adj, 1, 5)
```

Returns:

```
[True]
```

#### Implementation 2

```
def dfs(adj, x, y, visited=None, flag=False):
    if visited is None:
        visited = set()
    if x == y:
        flag = True
    if x not in visited:
        visited.add(x)
    for neigh in adj[x]:
        if neigh not in visited:
            dfs(adj, neigh, y, visited, flag)

    return flag
```

and:

```
dfs(adj, 1, 5)
```

Returns:

```
False
```

**Edited**

Thanks for the answer, I believed it solves the question of parameter resetting for recursive calls. But for the other side of the problem, I still need some help, that is, when does recursive calls overwrite a value of a parameter and inherit along the way to the top?

Let me elaborate with the above example. The following results are some `print`s traced from debugging `implementation 1` and `implementation 2`, ordered according to its finish time.

```
Intermediate_func       Implementation1   Implementation2    
dfs(adj, 4, 5)           [True]           True  
dfs(adj, 5, 5)           [True]           True  
dfs(adj, 3, 5)           [True]           False  
dfs(adj, 2, 5)           [True]           False 
dfs(adj, 1, 5)           [True]           False
```

Observing that `[True]` got copied down all the way to `dfs(adj, 1, 5)`. Following the execution order (`Implementation 1`), `dfs(adj, 1, 5)`, `dfs(adj, 2, 5)` and `dfs(adj, 3, 5)` are initiated to be `[]` until it sees `dfs(adj, 5, 5)`. Somehow, the `[True]` value from `dfs(adj, 5, 5)` is kept and passed down to `dfs(adj, 1, 5)`. Why can't the `True` value from `Implementation 2` be copied down to `dfs(adj, 1, 5)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use mutable default parameters. Python creates the function object only once. This means `flag=[]` is created only once and used all call to `dfs`.

Changing your first implementation to:

```
def dfs(adj, x, y, visited=None, flag=None):
    flag = []
    if visited is None:
        visited = set()
    if x == y:
        flag.append(True)
    if x not in visited:
        visited.add(x)
    for neigh in adj[x]:
        if neigh not in visited:
            dfs(adj, neigh, y, visited, flag)

    return flag
```

Now:

```
dfs(adj, 1, 5)
```

Returns:

```
[]
```

So the problem is the list that keeps the `True` (implementation 1) vs. `False`  that is reset each (recursive) function (implementation 2). Resetting the list to an empty list makes both implementations equivalent.

You need to move the returned flag if you want to move the information to your recursive calls:

```
def dfs(adj, x, y, visited=None, flag=False):
    if visited is None:
        visited = set()
    if x == y:
        flag = True
    if x not in visited:
        visited.add(x)
    for neigh in adj[x]:
        if neigh not in visited:
            #  save returned flag here
            flag = dfs(adj, neigh, y, visited, flag)

    return flag
```

Now:

```
dfs(adj, 1, 5)
```

Returns:

```
True
```